# Argument about nullspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Question:
Suppose $A_{m\times n}, B_{m \times n}$ are two matrices such that for all $b$, $Ax = b$ and $Bx = b$ have same solutions. Is it true that $A=B$?

My argument is as follows:

$  \forall\  b,x,  Ax = Bx = b\ \implies \forall x, (A-B)x = 0 $

Therefore, nullspace of $(A-B)$ has $n$ free variables. Therefore, the rank of matrix is $0$. Therefore $A-B = 0 \implies A = B$.

Is my argument correct? Or is it full of "slippery-slope"? If so, what details can improve my argument?

Thank you.

Comment: Implicit in your argument is that $b \in {\cal R} A$ (or $B$).

Comment: @copper.hat What does that notation mean? I am not familiar with it.

Comment: Range space. ${}{}$

Comment: @copper.hat Does that mean column space? Also, $Ax = b$ is the given part, so I am more concerned about the part after $(A-B)x = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Choose $x_0$. Then $x_0$ is a solution to $Ax=Ax_0$ of course and so it is a solution to $Bx=Ax_0$. Hence $A x_0 = B x_0$.

Comment: Is $x_0$ a specific vector, like one in the null space of A?
Also, this is similar to solution given in the book, but I was interested whether we could argue using the fact that $(A-B)x = 0$

Comment: It is an arbitrary vector in the domain of $A$.